# Android MediaPlayer wrong track duration

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

The problem is MP plays less time that track duration is. So track ends before it should in few seconds. I've got this bug only on some long tracks (one hour and more). Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is different duration values from `MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION` and `MediaPlayer.getDuration()`. Using only the last one solved my problem. Also should set the follow code in MP `onCompletion()`: `mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration())`.

Comment: It should be the same value, which device are you using? or are you using emulator with aosp code?

Comment: @Beetlej Im using moto G. Subj detected only on few long tracks. Other track ok.

Comment: Would you please help share the issue content?

Comment: @Beetlej I described issue behind. Now checked details: track duration is the same as you said, but track can stops before the end as I described in Q. So my answer solves this)